# Cannot get my bootable media to boot on my laptop

Tags: uefi, switch, bootable-media

My laptop: Acer Aspire Switch 10E
My processor:  Intel Atom Z3735F  (64 bit processor)
Came pre-installed with 32 bit windows 8.1 now upgraded to windows 10
I believe this laptop has a 32 bit UEFI
First boot device is USB CDROM in bios
Secure boot has been disabled

My bootable media are not booting (although they are being recognised at start up going by the blinking on the optical drive)

Many of these bootable Cds are Linux based (I think) and just do not boot - though secure boot is disabled. 
Neither do some of the uEFI boot supported cd/dvds

The only UEFI supported bootable CD that actually boots is acronis tru image bootable and when I checked in the folder structure it has the 32 bit and 64 bit efi files and their xml files too in the efi folder.

Other uefi boot cds/dvds did not have the 32 bit efi file.

What is going on.  What are my options and where do I go from here.

I have NO technical knowledge at all of these things and I have googled intensively to find a solution and hence have been able to use some technical jargon above.

Any solutions or work-arounds are requested in the most lucid and explanatory language preferably with step wise guidance and links

Thanks very much for any advice and help

Answer (score 0):

There may be additional settings in BIOS that need to be changed, such as "secure boot" (as distinct from UEFI) and "legacy boot". [According to KNGP14](http://community.acer.com/t5/2014-Archives/pxe-boot-a-aspire-switch-10/td-p/272152), "[T]o edit more Options in the Bios Settings... you have to set a "Super Visor Password" in the "Security" Tab... every time you want to enter the BIOS, you have to type in this password... be [sure]to remember it."

The *boot order* also must be changed in BIOS to put CD (or USB) first. but since you could boot from an Acronis disk, you must have done so.

Comment: I have already specified that i have disabled secure boot, created supervisor password and set the machine to boot first from USB cd. I think this has something to do with the 32 bit UEFI crap of which i understand nothing...